# Android Emulator Contacts Manager source code?

Tags: android, android-contacts, calllog

I'm looking to "Android emulator contacts manager" and it looks exactly what I need :).. Does anybody know if it possible to find source code of that application ( I hope some android project for eclipse :P ) ? If does not, can you suggest similar one, of course with source code.

Android v2.3.3

[image: Android Emulator Contacts Manager]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it. It's there: [The Android Open Source Contacts Project](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_contacts). You can browse other android application in parent repository.

Unfortunately they use *com.android.internal.** packages which can't be reused as I see..